# Known 2 quaternions from 2 IMUs, How can I get the quaternion to show the rotation

Tags: rotation, quaternions, euler-angles

As title mentioned, I want to get the rotation quaternion between two given quaternions. How is the algorithm and How to transfer it into Euler angle for better understanding?  Thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781129/when-i-have-two-orientation-quaternions-how-do-i-find-the-rotation-quaternion-n) for the first part of your question, and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles) can help with the second part.

Comment: I am sorry but but the rotation equation should be q2=r*q1*r.inverse() rather than q2=r*q1(even the dimension is not correct), and thus the r can not be simply equal to q2*q1.inverse().

Comment: Your equation describes rotation of a _vector_; combination of two quaternions is quaternion multiplication. Just have a read of the wiki page - it is correct, trust me.

Comment: yes it is correct, thanks a lot